# How do you add the following to a variable?

Tags: c#

I need to assign this to a variable but using double - double quotes isn't working:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="abc" TagName="header" Src="../Header.ascx" %>
```

This is throwing all sorts of errors:

```
string stringToAdd = @""<%@ Register TagPrefix="abc" TagName="header" Src="../Header.ascx" %>"";
```

How do I go about adding the above to a variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options:

**With `@` at the beginning:**

```
string stringToAdd = @"<%@ Register TagPrefix=""abc"" TagName=""header"" Src=""../Header.ascx"" %>";
```

Notice that each double quote is escaped by changing `"` to `""`.

**Without `@` at the beginning:**

```
string stringToAdd = "<%@ Register TagPrefix=\"abc\" TagName=\"header\" Src=\"../Header.ascx\" %>";
```

Notice that each double quote is escaped by changing `"` to `\"`.

Comment: this can get a little unreadable at points, in which case you may be better off defining a const string quote = "\""; and just using that in place of quotes within the string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, skip then with backslash `"\"`:

```
string stringToAdd = "<%@ Register TagPrefix=\"abc\" TagName=\"header\" Src=\"../Header.ascx\" %>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got the double-double quotes backwards:

```
string stringToAdd = @"<%@ Register TagPrefix=""abc"" TagName=""header"" Src=""../Header.ascx"" %>";
```